Trying to pass information from form into Stripe embedded Checkout
I have a route that the user selects the product they want, then on submit this pulls up a stripe checkout. To do this it uses JS to attach the id through a jsonify object and open checkout in a different route. I can not figure out how to pass to the checkout what price plan to charge for.
index.js
// Initialize Stripe.js
const stripe = Stripe('pk_test_YSXoqDoX1mJwM24nF3p5ZRwh');

initialize();

// Fetch Checkout Session and retrieve the client secret
async function initialize() {
  const fetchClientSecret = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("/create-checkout-session", {
  method: "POST",
});
const { clientSecret } = await response.json();
return clientSecret;
};

// Initialize Checkout
const checkout = await stripe.initEmbeddedCheckout({
fetchClientSecret,
 });

// Mount Checkout
checkout.mount('#checkout');
 }

I have to admit I copy pasted this from Stripe and do not understand JS
stripe_checkout.HTML
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}

<head>
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

 <div id="checkout">
  <!-- Checkout will insert the payment form here -->
 </div>
</body>



{% endblock %}

app.py
@app.route("/payments/",methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def payments():


id = request.args.get('id')

user = id


if request.method == 'POST' and "get_package" in request.form:

    user = request.form["user"]

    if "level1" in request.form:
        level = request.form["level1"]

      

    elif "level2" in request.form:
        level = request.form["level2"]

    else:
        level = None
        return "Please select a level"
    option = level

   
   
    return render_template("stripe_checkout.html", user=user, payment=True, level=level)    
    
return render_template("payment.html", user=user)

@app.route('/create-checkout-session', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def create_checkout_session():


  stripe.api_key = 'sk_test_951aYI7vV0278R8TumKtEwYt'

  session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
    line_items = [{
  'price_data': {
    'currency': 'usd',
    'product_data': {
      'name': 'T-shirt',
    },
    'unit_amount': 2000,
  },
  'quantity': 1,
 }],
mode = 'payment',
ui_mode = 'embedded',
 return_url = 'https://example.com/checkout/return?session_id=    .    {CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
)


return jsonify(clientSecret=session.client_secret)

I don't understand how to return the jsonify, and also show the html

Did you import jsonify from flask? Here's the example code on how to do it.
